# Unexpected "waiting for localhost"?

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

So I ran into something that kind of worried me today. Lately my computer has been kind of slow and I'm dealing with that, but today when I opened Facebook in Google Chrome, I noticed a message in the bottom left corner while it was loading the site that said:

> “Waiting for localhost.”

It was brief and I managed to notice it because my computer is slower than it used to and it caused Chrome to hang briefly, long enough for me to read it.

As I'm quite confident in that Facebook isn't running on my localhost, I'm wondering what could potentially make Chrome wait for localhost while I'm loading webpages from external servers. Is there a malware of some kind that I should be worrying about?

Unfortunately I have no other information than this to go on, and I have no idea how to further investigate this, if it generated any logs or whatever.

I'd appreciate any help in figuring out this matter!

Comment: Probably a victim of phishing.

Comment: Are you accessing Facebook through secure connection? (`https://` in the address bar, padlock icon **that says everything's fine when clicked**)

Comment: I'll be sure to give Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware a go & keep you posted on the progress, pnuts!

And indeed I'm accessing Facebook through https://, and it does say that everything is fine. That is why it confounds me that the browser insists on waiting for "localhost" for some reason.

Comment: What type of computer are you using?  What kind of plugins have you installed?   Some plugins like google-talk adds helper programs which may be listing on a port on localhost -- so check what ports are activly beeing listen on and post to this question what programs they are.

Comment: Have you checked your proxy settings? Perhaps some malware have modified them to use a proxy running on localhost.

Comment: Check "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" file. If you see a line like 127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com there's your problem.

Comment: Jimadine: That seems to have been the problem =) I've been able to fix it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While I do recommend you remain suspicious until you have a satisfactory answer, I have seen some "legitimate" locally-installed webproxy/firewall/filter types of software that do connect to localhost on an alternate port to provide the service.

Also fire this off in a command window as soon as you see suspicious activity:

```
netstat -b
```

It might help give some clarity on what is going on.